# Взять элемент из Fragment из основного activity

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть активити edit_activity.java, в котором я подключаю фрагменты. Именно в нем мне нужно получить определенный элемент, допустим, с `id=myEditText`. Как мне это сделать? Повторюсь, эта переменная мне нужна именно в edit_activity.java.

**Подключение**

```
Fragment fr1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment fr2 = new Fragment2();

TabsViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(fr1, "1");
    adapter.addFragment(fr2, "2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Таким образом, получается, у меня на экране есть `viewPager`, в котором я не могу програмно менять свойства элементов, тк не могу их получить( А мне очень нужно

Comment: А почему нельзя добавить getter и setter в класс фрагмента - и потом вызывать их из activity?

Comment: @AleksG Сейчас попробую)

Comment: @AleksG Нет, нельзя. Почему-то мои `public` методы не видны в моем основном активити